# Content-type in a GET request header

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, web, get

I'm finding it hard to understand if there are any implications of asking for a content-type header for GET requests.
I know that usually one should use accept header for GET, but what are the implications of using a content-type?

Comment: Ithink you should read about content negotiation.

Comment: GET requests can have "Accept" headers, which say which types of content the client understands. The server can then use that to decide which content type to send back.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Content type is used for the Content you are sending!
We can have multiple content type while sending Request, Could be JSON, XML and others etc.
Using content type will specify the server and Client that the Content we will send will be a JSON, XML, or any other type.